Understanding how to calculate partial trace
W.r.t. this:

I would like to understand how equation 6.29 follows from 6.28. Can anyone explain this to me?

The key here is that the tensor product satisfies $(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D)=AC\otimes BD$. Applied to the terms of $\rho$ in (6.27) this means
$$
|ab\rangle\langle cd|\overset{\text{Def.}}=(|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle)(\langle c|\otimes\langle d|)=|a\rangle\langle c|\otimes|b\rangle\langle d|\,.
$$
For example, $|00\rangle\langle 11|=|0\rangle\langle 1|\otimes|0\rangle\langle 1|$.
With this in mind the step from (6.28) to (6.29) is a straightforward calculation; I'll illlustrate it via two out of the eight of the terms that emerge:
\begin{align*}
(I\otimes \langle 0|)(|00\rangle\langle 00|)(I\otimes |0\rangle)&=(I\otimes \langle 0|)(|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes|0\rangle\langle 0|)(I\otimes |0\rangle)\\
&=I|0\rangle\langle 0|I\otimes \langle 0|0\rangle\langle0|0\rangle=|0\rangle\langle 0|
\end{align*}
(because $\langle 0|0\rangle=1$ and the tensor product with a number is just standard multiplication). Also
\begin{align*}
(I\otimes \langle 1|)(|00\rangle\langle 11|)(I\otimes |1\rangle)&=(I\otimes \langle 1|)(|0\rangle\langle 1|\otimes|0\rangle\langle 1|)(I\otimes |1\rangle)\\
&=I|0\rangle\langle 1|I\otimes \langle 1|0\rangle\langle1|1\rangle=0
\end{align*}
because $\langle 1|0\rangle=0$. I trust that with this in mind you can finish the calculation yourself.

thanks. sometimes I think they can get any result they want.
